# Retraining for cyber security. What's the quickest way into the field?

Tags: recruitment, hiring, security

I’m 26 and I recently graduated with a bachelor's degree in psychology, but it hasn’t proven to be useful in finding a job. I understand there are a lot of job opportunities (with many specializations) in the field of cyber security, but I have also read a lot of horror stories from people who have degrees and/or certifications but who can’t find work. Is there one area or another of cyber security that would be quicker to prepare/train for than others, would have entry level job openings, and would have opportunities for career growth?

Comment: We must live in different worlds. As a psychologist, you want to specialize in cyber-security, even though you are aware that you will be unemployed (considering that even certified professionals cannot find jobs)? Please modify the question, so it makes more sense. Also, are there lots of opportunities for cyber-security professionals, or not? You have a very ambiguous way of presenting information.

Comment: At your age jumping into tech-career will be very hard. Talking from personal experience. Safest bet is to stick with programming or IT, build foundation and switch.But even then it is very risky, you may end up with 1-2 year gaps.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in Cyber-security; IT is only one part of it. I know of a very successful person in the Cybersecurity industry with a similar humanities degree who specialises in the human behaviour side of cyber-security like how people are fooled in to giving out passwords or sending money to people pretending to be their boss.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace Omar! Unfortunately [we can't give personal career advice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/25739) on this site. We can't answer a question that depends so heavily on your own abilities, preferences or circumstances. We *can* answer specific questions on how to handle a workplace situation, accomplish a goal or come to a decision on a practical problem. If you can reword your question to fit those criteria please do so, otherwise your post will likely remain closed. Check out the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very risky move, but it's possible if you do enough.
I'd say, take some certifications, mastering cyber security skills by learning Cryptography, Security Design, Emerging Threats and Defenses and Network Security.
You will be doing your own showcase expertise through the certification.
Gain practical knowledge by participating in projects that give hands-on learning experience.
Get mentored by industry experts who bring significant experience.

But those ain't that smooth as it sounds, you need to take your first step so you will be acknowledge in tech-area, get a job related to Tech-Cyber Security, gain experience, build your network, and go deeper.

I repeat, it's a very risky move.